# Как в скомпилированном проекте на vue считать json файл

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В общем есть проект на vue, и нужно каким то образом добавить в него json файл, чтобы его можно было в дальнейшем редактировать. Есть ли какие то способы это реализовать?

> в этом jsone  будут находиться текста, которые можно будет в дальнейшем редактировать, но чтобы после редактирования не пришлось пересобирать проект

Comment: А почему бы не сделать условный config.js в котором возвращать этот Json?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал через PHP:

```
<script>
    var jsonData = <?= file_get_contents($filePath) ?>;
</script>
```